# How to get list of messages By Gmail Api Without NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-platform, iframe, gmail-api

I am creating a project in which I can get the list of **Inbox** or **All Mails** without node js.
I tried to search similar projects everywhere but I didn't find exactly what I want.

I tried to make some changes, but still not working.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Gmail API demo</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Gmail API demo</h1>

      <button id="authorize-button" class="btn btn-primary">Authorize</button>

      <table class="table table-striped table-inbox">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>From</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Date/Time</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var clientId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';
      var apiKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
      }

      function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({
          client_id: clientId,
          scope: scopes,
          immediate: true
        }, handleAuthResult);
      }

      function handleAuthClick() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({
          client_id: clientId,
          scope: scopes,
          immediate: false
        }, handleAuthResult);
        return false;
      }

      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        if(authResult && !authResult.error) {
          loadGmailApi();
          $('#authorize-button').remove();
          $('.table-inbox').removeClass("hidden");
        } else {
          $('#authorize-button').removeClass("hidden");
          $('#authorize-button').on('click', function(){
            handleAuthClick();
          });
        }
      }

      function loadGmailApi() {
        gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', displayInbox);
      }

      function displayInbox() {
        var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
          'userId': 'me',
          'labelIds': 'INBOX',
          'maxResults': 10
        });

        request.execute(function(response) {
          $.each(response.messages, function() {
            var messageRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
              'userId': 'me',
              'id': this.id
            });

            messageRequest.execute(appendMessageRow);
          });
        });
      }

      function appendMessageRow(message) {
        $('.table-inbox tbody').append(
          '<tr>\
            <td>'+getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'From')+'</td>\
            <td>\
              <a href="#message-modal-' + message.id +
                '" data-toggle="modal" id="message-link-' + message.id+'">' +
                getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'Subject') +
              '</a>\
            </td>\
            <td>'+getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'Date')+'</td>\
          </tr>'
        );

        $('body').append(
          '<div class="modal fade" id="message-modal-' + message.id +
              '" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">\
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">\
              <div class="modal-content">\
                <div class="modal-header">\
                  <button type="button"\
                          class="close"\
                          data-dismiss="modal"\
                          aria-label="Close">\
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>\
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">' +
                    getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'Subject') +
                  '</h4>\
                </div>\
                <div class="modal-body">\
                  <iframe id="message-iframe-'+message.id+'" srcdoc="<p>Loading...</p>">\
                  </iframe>\
                </div>\
              </div>\
            </div>\
          </div>'
        );

        $('#message-link-'+message.id).on('click', function(){
          var ifrm = $('#message-iframe-'+message.id)[0].contentWindow.document;
          $('body', ifrm).html(getBody(message.payload));
        });
      }

      function getHeader(headers, index) {
        var header = '';

        $.each(headers, function(){
          if(this.name === index){
            header = this.value;
          }
        });
        return header;
      }

      function getBody(message) {
        var encodedBody = '';
        if(typeof message.parts === 'undefined')
        {
          encodedBody = message.body.data;
        }
        else
        {
          encodedBody = getHTMLPart(message.parts);
        }
        encodedBody = encodedBody.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/').replace(/\s/g, '');
        return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(encodedBody)));
      }

      function getHTMLPart(arr) {
        for(var x = 0; x <= arr.length; x++)
        {
          if(typeof arr[x].parts === 'undefined')
          {
            if(arr[x].mimeType === 'text/html')
            {
              return arr[x].body.data;
            }
          }
          else
          {
            return getHTMLPart(arr[x].parts);
          }
        }
        return '';
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Problem is with **Same Site Cookie** on iframe and other cookies.
These things are affecting gmail requests.
[image: Issues]

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: There was no errors

Comment: Use the Chrome debugger and step through the code.

Comment: @JohnHanley I used Chrome Debugger and Stepped through the code but still it is not working.

Comment: This github repo works well with JS and PY as hosting give it a try. The codes are very similar to what you have written . https://github.com/Chettaniya/gmail-api-with-inbox-in-js

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows

`var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'+'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send';`

The above gives you one continuous long string i.e. `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonlyhttps://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send`

What you need is a list of scopes. Since they are multiple scopes, they are separated by a space. If you look at the code you're referring to, it has a space at the end of the first scope i.e

```
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly '+
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send';
```

You can also try your code with just one scope and see if it works, before you then try to figure out if multiple scopes are separated by a blank space or comma.

Comment: I tried your suggested code. But still that popup is not appearing!

Comment: Add ```console.log``` statements at the beginning of each function, reload your page and find out which function is not being called. That should tell you where your code is failing

Comment: Also, when you say you tried my suggested code, did you try it with only 1 scope?

Comment: I used console.log() at starting and ending of functions. It seems that console logs are not printing out at function handleAuthResult()

Comment: This is the flow of your code  ```client.js onload > handleClientLoad > checkAuth > handleAuthResult```.  If you say ```checkAuth``` was successfully called but ```handleAuthResult``` is not being called, then the issue seems to be within ```checkAuth```. It could be that you have a wrong client id or your scopes are invalid (maybe the URLs are wrong) or you should try a single scope.

Comment: I tried it with only one scope still not working. As for client Id - I rechecked my client Id, I thought it was old and created new Id and replaced Old one. Still it is not working!